# Optimization step in Apprenticeship Learning via Inverse Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, optimization, math

Why the optimization step of the algorithm a quadratic program?  *[See: [Apprenticeship Learning via Inverse Reinforcement Learning](https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icml04-apprentice.pdf); page 3]*

Isn't the objective function linear? Why don't we treat the problem as LPQC (linear program with quadratic constraints)?

Comment: Could you perhaps include a link to a relevant paper? It looks like you have a very specific algorithm in mind, and if you can link to it, others will be better able to help.

Comment: https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icml04-apprentice.pdf

Comment: the algorithm is in the 3rd page